# Tema apenas em uma página Wordpress. É possível?

Tags: wordpress

Tem um site em Wordpress que está com um tema específico. Ou seja, todos os posts e páginas estão com a aparência desse tema.

Acontece que preciso criar uma nova página, e essa página tem que ter o tema diferente do site inteiro.

É possível, apenas naquela página, mudar o tema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Plugins para múltiplos temas

Sem envolver programação, há pelo menos dois plugins para se fazer isso:

- [jonradio Multiple Themes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/)
- [Page Theme](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-theme/)

Não usei nenhum, então sugiro que teste e veja se algum deles lhe atende.

## Diferentes layouts em um tema

Se você está implementando ou modificando um tema, também é possível em um mesmo tema criar tipos de layouts diferentes. Vários temas permitem você escolher o tipo de layout para cada página ou post.

Por exemplo, em uma página você não quer o menu lateral, na outra você quer sem o menu. Bons temas possuem layouts diferentes para a página inicial, página de contato, etc.

Eu acredito que essa solução é a melhor para a maioria dos casos, a não ser que haja uma nacessidade muito específica, já que não é algo comum mudar completamente um tema de uma página para outro.

Ficaria muito extenso detalhar o passo-a-passo para se fazer isso, mas basicamente você precisa criar um arquivo PHP adicionar com um cabeçalho específico e o Wordpress vai encontrar o layout novo automaticamente. Veja a [documentação](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado, cara.

Answer (score 2):

O código base é bem simples, ajuste o slug da página e o nome do tema:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Theme for page
 */

add_filter( 'template', 'change_theme_wpse_12931' );
add_filter( 'option_template', 'change_theme_wpse_12931' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'change_theme_wpse_12931' );

function change_theme_wpse_12931( $template = '' ) 
{
    if( is_page('test-page') ) 
        $template = 'twentyten';

    return $template;
}
```

Provavelmente, você vai precisar fazer ajustes finos porque podem dar erros de 404 para alguns recursos do tema original e que o WP vai tentar buscar no tema alternativo, no meu sistema local está o TwentyFourteen e dá esta falha:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://example.dev/wp-content/themes/twentyten/genericons/genericons.css`

<sub>O código é [desta pergunta no WordPress Developers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12931/12615).</sub>

---

Ou então, como [comenta o utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15854/tema-apenas-em-uma-pagina-wordpress-e-possivel/15882#15882), pode-se usar um *page template* com header e footer personalizados, neste exemplo o template vai chamar o arquivo `header-test-page.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Virtual theme
 */
if( is_page('test-page') ) 
    get_header('test-page');
else
    get_header(); ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Optei por fazer sem envolver programação, pois precisava de uma solução rápida.